# Saving all words as python source code including punctuation

Tags: python, unicode

As in python 2.7, I can save all unicode string into Python source code.

In the following code,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#coding:utf-8
a = u'我很好,你呢?'

with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(repr(a))
```

What I expect is giving me back a txt with following wording

> u'\u6211\u5f88\u597d\u002C\u4f60\u5462\u003F'

but turns out it is

> u'\u6211\u5f88\u597d,\u4f60\u5462?'

Why punctuation is not handled? Is there anyway to handle the punctuation too?

**Updated**:
Though I will take @Blckknght advisement in comment as using other encoding is still fine for my purpose, but I am still open to see if any answer about saving punctuation as python string. Thx.

Comment: The punctuation is there, it just doesn't need `\uXXXX` formatting, since it's part of the ASCII character set. Why do you want `\u002C` and `\u003F` when `,` and `?` work just as well?

Comment: @Blckknght, because in the next step I need to do some language related analysis on it. To keep things simple, I want all wording has `\uXXXX` format, so I dun need to set specific rules to handle punctuation.

Comment: If you just want to process the data as codepoints, use a different format than a Python string. Something like `''.join(format(ord(c), '04x') for c in a)` might do well for that, or you could space separate things if that made the processing easier.

Comment: It's hard to say what to use without knowing what the next step is. You could look into using `io.open(..., encoding=...)` for opening the file for writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repr()` has a fixed representation for Unicode strings.  You have to write your own function if you want it to display differently:

```
#coding:utf8

def my_repr(s):
    return "u'" + ''.join(r'\u{:04x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in s) + "'"

s = u'我很好,你呢?'
print my_repr(s)
```

Output:

```
u'\u6211\u5f88\u597d\u002c\u4f60\u5462\u003f'
```

(But this feels like an XY-problem)